# ERROR running force:source:deploy: This command is required to run from within an SFDX project

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-plugin, github

I am trying to use GitHub actions to deploy code to my developer org.  While running the workflow i am getting error like. I am unable to figure where it is wrong

[image]

Below is the structure in github.

[image]
[image]

sfdx-project.json file

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true
    }
  ],
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "48.0"
}
```

i am using below github workflow file

```
#..github/workflows/main.yml
name: githubactioncicd
on: 
  # Trigger the workflow on push or pull request,
  # but only for the main branch
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@main
      if: github.event.action == 'opened' || github.event.action == 'synchronize'
    - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: '10.x'

    - name: Install Salesforce CLI
      run: |
        npm install sfdx-cli
        node_modules/sfdx-cli/bin/run --version
        node_modules/sfdx-cli/bin/run plugins --core
      
    - name: Authenticate DevHub
      run: |
        echo "${SALESFORCE_JWT_SECRET_KEY}" > server.key
        node_modules/sfdx-cli/bin/run force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid ${{ secrets.SALESFORCE_CONSUMER_KEY }} --jwtkeyfile server.key --username ${{ secrets.SALESFORCE_DEVHUB_USERNAME}} --instanceurl https://login.salesforce.com --setdefaultdevhubusername
      env:
        SALESFORCE_JWT_SECRET_KEY: ${{ secrets.SALESFORCE_JWT_SECRET_KEY }}
    - name: Deploy source
      run: node_modules/sfdx-cli/bin/run force:source:deploy --manifest manifest/package.xml
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a project file (sfdx-project.json) in the root path? Sorry but maybe you can show or tell the files after the .gitignore.

Comment: Hi Jeferson..I have added the screesnshot..

Comment: No such file ..do you have a package xml file ?? inside manifest folder ..@learnjqueery
try running this from another terminal maybe cli or powershell or bash

Comment: package.xml file is there.. if i run it in vscode terminal.. it is giving.. === Deployed Source
No results found.. and the changes are not deployed//

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong parameter. You have to use [-x MANIFEST] instead of [-p SOURCEPATH] working with package.xml :[image] as explain in the documentation (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm)

Comment: Hi Badbaxx.. after updating it .. i am getting the following error.. -->                                 Run node_modules/sfdx-cli/bin/run force:source:deploy --manifest manifest/package.xml
/home/runner/work/_temp/80c3953c-2ccb-49cf-94a8-35ff9066dc89.sh: line 1: node_modules/sfdx-cli/bin/run: No such file or directory
Error: Process completed with exit code 127.

Comment: Try to add sfdx in your deploy command (run: node_modules/sfdx-cli/bin/run **sfdx** force:source:deploy [...]

Comment: Same error --> Run node_modules/sfdx-cli/bin/run sfdx force:source:deploy --manifest /manifest/package.xml
/home/runner/work/_temp/4e38dc02-6fca-4ceb-b1a8-4fd9eabc0629.sh: line 1: node_modules/sfdx-cli/bin/run: No such file or directory
Error: Process completed with exit code 127.

Comment: remove the / before manifest in your path to manifest to get    **node_modules/sfdx-cli/bin/run force:source:deploy --manifest manifest/package.xml**

Comment: same error.. i have added the screen shot..removed sfdx command also.. but facing same error..

Comment: This is a bit weird. I'm not really familiar to github action. Is there a way to run a **echo $PWD** command before to be sure the command is run from the good folder ?

Answer (score 0):

The command you are using is this

```
$ sfdx force:source:deploy -p path/to/source
```

but when you are specifying a manifest you gotta use this

```
$ sfdx force:source:deploy -x path/to/package.xml
```

And next time whenever in a fix like this simply do

```
$ sfdx force:source:deploy --help
```

(any command without parameter and --help)

this is similar to the man pages of linux it will give all details regarding the commands as well as associated parameters

Comment: I tried the following commands but it is still failing.

<----Code Line used --->

$ sfdx force:source:deploy -x force-app/main/default/

----- >

Error message : on Pipeline
ERROR running force:source:deploy:  This command is required to run from within an SFDX project.
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1

Comment: its not recognising your project as a SFDX one this happens sometimes,  try updating sfdx or creating a new project sadly

Comment: Thanks, when you say new project are you referring to the GitLab project or sfdc?

Comment: sfdx project ...